# Vegetable garden plant identification: white tuber, tall leafy growth

Tags: identification

My garden is a shared garden, and the plot I have was gardened by someone else last year.  I have no idea who it was, so I can't ask them the following question.

What is this plant in the picture below?  When I was prepping my garden plot I noticed some sort of white radish/carrot-like root or tuber that had started growing leaves.  It had been cut by a shovel or the tiller about two inches from the top so I have no idea how long the original root/tuber was.  I was curious and decided to plant it in my garden; now it is thriving quite well.

Links to other websites that would allow me to figure out myself what this plant is will also be appreciated.

I live in New Jersey.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was it looks like woad (isatis tinctoria) getting ready to bolt to flower, due to the shape of the leaf and prominent white central vein.

Comment: Based on what I've seen Googling "woad plant bolt", I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

This is Evening Primrose (Oenothera biennis). Very common where I live.

[image: Evening Primrose in bloom with foliage]
https://www.flickr.com/photos/starr-environmental/9214878192/